# How to perform calculation in DataGridView when a checkbox is ticked C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

[image]

- I have this case in C# Datagridview.

I want to calculate 3-Piece Average, on textbox shown above, whenever checkbox is checked.

I'm using this logic below:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DataGridView data = this.qualitySetupDataGridView;
        try
        {
            int count = 0;
            double Sum = 0;

            for (int k = 0; k < data.Rows.Count - 1; k++)
            {

                if (data.Rows[k].Cells[5].Value != null)
                {
                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(data.Rows[k].Cells[5].Value) == true)
                    {

                        double EndsPerInch = double.Parse(data.Rows[k].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                        Sum = Sum + EndsPerInch;
                        count++;
                        double Average = Sum / count;
                        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Round(Average, 2));

                    }

                }

                else
                {

                    textBox1.Clear();

                }
            }
```

- The code is working as it suppose to be.
- but first time, when a single checkbox is selected, I get Invalid Cast Exception Error.
- when a second checkbox is selected I again get Invalid Cast Exception Error.
- When third checkbox is selected I do not get Invalid Cast Exception Error.
- and then the program works as it suppose to be.
- The question here is this why it pops up invalid cast exception error in the beginning?.

is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Obviously it would help a) see the relevant code of the DGV and b) to know which line gives the invalid cast exception

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with a more object oriented logic so that you can easily calculate your average without having to actually read the grid.

For that you should:

1.Create a class that contains your records, something like this:

```
public class MyRecord
{
     public double EndsPerInch { get; set; }
     public bool Checked { get; set; }
     //...and other properties I can't see from your screenshot
}
```

2.Instanciate a list of MyRecords, that is to say the list of records you'll display in your grid:

```
List<MyRecord> MyRecords = new List<MyRecord>();
```

3.Create a method that fills your list of records with your data and bind it in your datagridview

```
private void LoadGrid()
{
    //Creating the list of records
    MyRecords.Add(new MyRecord { Checked = false, EndsPerInch = 92});
    MyRecords.Add(new MyRecord { Checked = false, EndsPerInch = 56 });
    MyRecords.Add(new MyRecord { Checked = false, EndsPerInch = 100 });

    //Binding the list of records to the datagridview
    //By doing so, a checkbox column will automatically be generated and bound
    //to the "Checked" property of your class
    dataGridView1.DataSource = MyRecords;
}
```

Now that you have everythings that allows you to bind your data properly. Everytime the user wil check a value in the column "Checked", the property of the object record will be updated as well.
From here it becomes very easy to calculate the average by selecting the checked values from your collection of records:

```
private double CalculateAverage(List<MyRecord> MyRecords)
{
    double Sum = 0;

    //Getting the list of checked records and calculating sum
    List<MyRecord> Checked = MyRecords.Where(x => x.Checked).ToList();
    foreach (MyRecord mr in Checked)
        Sum += mr.EndsPerInch;

    //Calculating and returning average
    return Sum / Checked.Count;
}
```